# Tcl proc to resize images with transparency

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to resize images on-the-fly that have transparency using a Tcl proc.

The images (gif, png) are mostly small (128x128 typically).

I am trying to avoid having precomputed images for each size.

I also want to avoid using external executables (such as pnmscale, convert, etc.) for platform reasons.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What about [this wiki article](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Image+scaling)?

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks, will try. (I came across it before posting, but for reasons I can''t remember thought it did not apply.)

Comment: Do you want a pure Tcl solution or are you willing to use some C code (which could be built as an extension or statically linked to make a custom _wish_) to get something much faster?

Comment: @DonalFellows: For now a pure Tcl solution is desirable, speed not really an issue (unless terribly slow). I am still working through Jerry's suggestion at the moment (I am trying to figure out why I decided not to use it previously :-().

Comment: How do you represent the images?

Comment: @Andreas: I don't understand. The images are .gif, .png.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok, I'll try harder :) Source format is .gif and .png files. Target format is also .gif and .png files, yes? As opposed to a tcl list full of hex, or tk internal representation such as canvas bitmap. Many options here

Comment: @Andreas: I'm not sure I am answering your question, but it doesn't matter to me as long as I can use the result in a Tcl/Tk command.

Comment: @Jerry: A small modification of the image% proc in the article referenced did the trick. Much appreciated.

Comment: Except for transparency and I think I need some sort of dithering (or whatever the correct term is) as the resized image is a bit 'edgy'.

Comment: Ok I hope it goes well :)